# Proving by induction: $2^n > n^3 $ for any natural number $n > 9$

Tags: inequality, induction

I need to prove that $$ 2^n > n^3\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N, \;n>9.$$

Now that is actually very easy if we prove it for real numbers using calculus. But I need a proof that uses mathematical induction.

I tried the problem for a long time, but got stuck at one step - I have to prove that:

> $$ k^3 > 3k^2 + 3k + 1 $$

Hints???

Comment: $k \leqslant k^2$, $1 \leqslant k^2$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/439026/462).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your "subproof":

Try proof by induction (another induction!) for $k \geq 7$

$$k^3 > 3k^2 + 3k + 1$$

And you may find it useful to note that $k\leq k^2, 1\leq k^2$

$$3k^2 + 3k + 1 \leq 3(k^2) + 3(k^2) + 1(k^2) = 7k^2 \leq k^3 \quad\text{when}??$$

Comment: That's where I am stuck. I had myself thought to use induction for this...but am not able to figure out how to prove it. I think Daniel's hint will be useful - though still don't know how.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback +1

Answer (score 13):

For another way just using $n>9$, 
note that when $n=10$, $2^n = 1024 > 1000 = n^3$. Now suppose that $2^n>n^3$ for $n>9$. Then,

$\begin{align*}
2^{n+1} &= 2\cdot2^n \\
&>2n^3 \\
&= n^3 +n^3 \\
&> n^3 + 9n^2 \\
&= n^3 + 3n^2 + 6n^2 \\
&>n^3 + 3n^2 +54n \\ 
&=n^3+3n^2+3n +51n\\
&>n^3+3n^2+3n+1 \\
&= (n+1)^3.
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way. Suppose $k>9$. Then:
$$ \begin{align*}
k^3&=(k)k^2\\
&>9k^2\\
&=3k^2+3k^2+3k^2\\
&=3k^2+3(k)k+3(k)^2\\
&>3k^2+3(9)k+3(9)^2\\
&=3k^2+27k+243\\
&>3k^2+3k+1\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Awesome. This one is nice too! Although I think it's quite similar to what Daniel and amWhy suggested

Answer (score 2):

If $P(n): 2^n>n^3$

$n=10, P(10): 2^{10}=1024$ and $10^3=1000$

Let $P(n)$ is true for $n=m\implies 2^m>m^3$

Now, $P(m+1): 2^{m+1}=2\cdot 2^m>2m^3$ which we need to be $>(m+1)^3$

$\implies 2>\left(1+\frac1m\right)^3 $

If $m=2, \left(1+\frac1m\right)^3=\frac{27}8>2$

If $m=3, \left(1+\frac1m\right)^3=\frac{64}{27}>2$

If $m=4, \left(1+\frac1m\right)^3=\frac{125}{64}<2$

$\implies  2>\left(1+\frac1m\right)^3$ for $m=4$

and $\left(1+\frac1m\right)^3>\left(1+\frac1{m+1}\right)^3\implies 2>\left(1+\frac1m\right)^3$ for $m\ge 4$

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote after the $P(m+1)$ step - where did you get that implication from?

Comment: @ParthThakkar, $P(m+1): 2^{m+1}>(m+1)^3$ and from $P(m),2^{m+1}=2(2^m)>2(m^3)$. SO it's sufficient to prove $2m^3>(m+1)^3\iff 2>(1+\frac1m)^3$

Comment: Aah... didn't see that. I don't understand how I can get so silly!!

Comment: @ParthThakkar, please get back to me if you have any doubt, query

Comment: No, I understood this. Thanks! Just because I didn't notice the $P(n)$ step, I got confused, else this is quite straight forward.

Comment: Wait, I remember that on dividing inequalities, we reach some absurdity. I know that multiplication of inequalities is always valid (i.e. when the sign permits). So, let me do the transition from $P(m)$ to $P(m+1)$ by multiplication. $P(m) \implies 1/2^m < 1/m^3$. But since the sign reverses, we can't multiply the $P(m)$ and $P(m+1)$ equations. So, how is it working?

Comment: For example of getting absurdity on diving inequalities, consider $ 2 < 3$ and $4 < 6$.

Comment: @ParthThakkar, $P(m): 2^m>m^3$ is a statement.  $2^{m+1}=2\cdot 2^m>2m^3$ if we assume $P(m)$ is true. Now, if we can prove $2m^3>(m+1)^3,$ we are done

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9553/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-parth-thakkar)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You can use that if $k\ge10$, then $k^3\ge 10k^2=3k^2+7k^2$.

(Another approach would be to use that $\frac{(k+1)^3}{k^3}=(1+\frac{1}{k})^3\le
(11/10)^3<2$ for $k\ge10$.

Comment: The first approach works nicely!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem,
$2^n > n^3$,
 is equivalent to
$n < 2^{n/3}$.

Suppose
$n < 2^{n/3}$.
Then
$2^{(n+1)/3}
=2^{1/3}2^{n/3}
> n 2^{1/3}
$
and
$n 2^{1/3} > n+1
\iff n (2^{1/3}-1) > 1
\iff n > \frac1{2^{1/3}-1}
\iff n > 3.847...
$.

So, if
$n \ge 4$
and
$n^3 < 2^n$,
then
$(n+1)^3 < 2^{n+1}$.

Since
$1000 = 10^3 < 2^{10} = 1024$,
$n^2 < 2^n$
for $n \ge 10$.